# Unselect a default checkbox when all other box are checked

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML layout which has several checkboxes, one of the options is `ALL` and other options. When user clicks other options, `ALL` should be `unchecked` and when no other options are selected `ALL` should be checked.

here is the example: https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/JLBdv

this works but I want to change the layout so the input is in a list.

```
<ul>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="category" class="all" checked>
<label>All</label></li>
<li>
<input type="checkbox" name="category" value=".category-football"><label>Football</label>
</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="category" value=".category-running"><label>Running </label></li><ul>
```

but if I put the input fields inside the list, the original code is no longer working.

how can I change the original js to work with checkboxes inside the list?

Answer (score 0):

Just **add class names to your inputs**.

Example: ALL input can be **class='checkme_all'** and other inputs **class='checkme'**

```
<ul>
<li>
<input class='checkme_all' type="checkbox" name="category" class="all" checked>
<label>All</label>
</li>
<li>
<input class='checkme' type="checkbox" name="category" value=".category-football">
<label>Football</label>
</li>
<li>
<input class='checkme' type="checkbox" name="category" value=".category-running">
<label>Running </label>
</li>
<ul>
```

Then **use jQuery to provide desired behavior**:

```
$('.checkme').on('change', function() {
    if($('.checkme_all').prop('checked')) {
        $('.checkme_all').prop('checked', false)
    }
})

$('.checkme_all').on('change', function() {
        $('.checkme').prop('checked', false)
})
```

**Result**:

[image]

Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CyberneticSean/s5jknbwh/1/)

Comment: thanks I tried this using the origin code but it is not working https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eoQBZm

Comment: I used your original code. I only added class names and used jQuery. Do you have jQuery loaded?

Comment: ok I fixed it https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NmEbbo but now there is an issue, for the first check, it also checks the all box, can you see it?

Comment: thanks for the fiddle, but I have to keep using the existing code with same js but modifying it since I am using isotop, if you check my codepen you can see that if you click on the other option, then all is selected as well, then it is fixed after you select the second checkbox, any fix for that issue?

Comment: also when none is checked, all should be checked